# Ionic serve VS ionic serve -c

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm new in Ionic and using Ionic 3.9.2

I got several terminal commands to serve my ionic-app but, I'm not getting any difference between these two commands.

```
ionic serve
```

and

```
ionic serve -c
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basically short form of `ionic serve --consolelogs` for printing the log of you app in ionic CLI.(see the image)

There is second command to debug the app which is `ionic serve --verbose`

Hope this helps you to find out the difference. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`ionic serve -c`

or

```
ionic serve --consolelogs
```

will Print app console logs to your Ionic CLI.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`ionic serve -c` will print console logs. If you have a mobile device connected on same wifi, then you can also view your app on the device as well using the [ionDevApp](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/devapp/) .

Answer (score 0):

1. To run in basic mode use

> ionic serve

2. To run with console log in CLI

> ionic serve -c

3. To run with livereload with console log in CLI

> ionic serve -lc

4. To run with liverelaod in CLI

> ionic serve -l

5. To run in android with livereload with console log in CLI

> ionic run android -lc

6. To run in iOS with livereload with console log in CLI

> ionic run ios -lc

Hope it helps